QGIS Server missing DB Manager providers on Docker/Debian
i´m triying to create a QGIS Server container on Docker, following the example in documentation: docs. The purpose of this container is to export some layers from a .gdb file to an external PostGIS database via PyQGIS API. However when I am running the class:

QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(lyr, uri, "postgres", lyr.crs() )

i get the following error:  'Unable to load postgres provider'
Listing the providers with: QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
neither postgres or other spatial db providers appears.
Is there any option to add these providers or the 'DB Manager' plugin to the running container, via the dockerfile?
